# MS Project 2016 - VBA Cycle Time Issues (Extraction to Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have numerous *macros that seem to be slowing down when interfacing with MS Project* (e.g., reading data and processing it) *in MS Office 2016*. It could be my underlying code, mechanisms for obtaining/storing the data, but I'm not sure and would appreciate input.

I was just writing a new macro for extracting MSP data into an array (held in memory I thought this would be fastest, but it seemed to struggle to even do this). The idea being that the array memory access 'should' be faster than bridging from MS Excel to the Project referenced when needing to extract/place data? Perhaps this is incorrect.

Aim: Hold 3 parts of each MS Project Resource in Array, eventually iterate over array and place into Excel for additional use/processing.

The initial 'read' never quite completed (at 926 of my 1300 resources) before I broke the code to review.

**Ideas on the below, or for interfacing with the MSP 2016 Reference library? It seems to have become very slow compared to just working within MS Excel.**

Subroutine:

```
  Private Sub cb_IMSResourceImport_Click()
        Dim Prj As Project
        Set Prj = GetObject(Me.cboMaintainToProject.Value)
        Dim ResourceMatrix() As String
        Prj.Application.WindowActivate Prj.Name

        ReDim ResourceMatrix(Prj.Resources.Count, 2)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Range("A2:C" & C`Str(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).ClearContents

       For i = 1 To UBound(ResourceMatrix)
            ResourceMatrix(i - 1, 0) = Prj.Resources(i).ID
            ResourceMatrix(i - 1, 1) = Prj.Resources(i).Name
            ResourceMatrix(i - 1, 2) = Prj.Resources(i).Code
       Next i

       For i = 0 To UBound(ResourceMatrix)
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ResourceMatrix(i, 0)
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = ResourceMatrix(i, 1)
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = ResourceMatrix(i, 2)
       Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Project 2013 and a mocked-up schedule with 2000 resources, your code took less than 2 minutes to run. That said, if you have many schedules open, calculation left on, etc. it could take longer.

However, there is another way to copy data such as this from Project to Excel that is very fast—use the clipboard.

```
Private Sub ExtractResources()

    Dim prj As MSProject.Project
    Set prj = GetObject(Me.cboMaintainToProject.Value)
    Dim msp As MSProject.Application
    Set msp = prj.Application
    msp.WindowActivate prj.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Range("A2:C" & CStr(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).ClearContents

    msp.ViewApply "Resource Sheet"

    msp.SelectSheet
    msp.EditCopy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Resource Table").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Note: Modify the Resource View (or create your own) to define which columns to export out of Project. If you want the ID column to be exported, check the definition of the table used with the resource view to make sure the first column is not locked, otherwise it won't be included in the SelectSheet method.

Comment: So I have debated this approach and I need to go see if it is any faster. I have a feeling, in many instances, building a custom table with VBA based upon a user column selection in Excel headers and simply copying/pasting the data may be faster. I wonder after where the cross-over exists however. Surely there is a column/row limit to the data where the Array pull becomes more efficient.